# Mapping lat/lon to zip code level or climate region level

Tags: mapping

I have  a CFSR  30-year  climatology .nc file. I could read in the file and  get  lat, lon , date  and temperature. Now I  need roll up these information to a zip code then later to climate region level.

Where could I find such mapping?

I could find a zip code shapefile, I'm thinking I could find all the points within each zip code then roll up to region level.

Does anybody have more straightforward method?

I'm using R or Python to load the data.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: @MappaGnosis  I'm using R or Python to load the data.